# How many multiplexers is too much?

Tags: fpga, vhdl, multiplexer, signal-processing, routing

This is a general question. I have a specific task that I am working on. For this task, my solution requires around 300 multiplexers with all of them 16 inputs and 16 bits per input, and a single output. Naturally, at the end of the line I also need 300 demultiplexers obviously. Is this just too much? I am basically trying to find an easy, clean and non-demanding way to route some wide signals in VHDL.

Comment: Have you already chosen an FPGA? Or at least a family of FPGAs? Do you have a price target? A $1000 FPGA can surely do this, a $5 one surely can't. So the question becomes is your project worth spending enough on to afford the minimal one that can.

Comment: It's only "too much" if you can't build a practical solution. It might be "too many" if there are simpler solutions that you've not seen.

Comment: The tools will tell you if it is "too much".  You'll need to know the required clock speed.  And you should consider if you are willing to introduce pipeline stages to make timing.  Overall your need is not clearly enough stated for more specific guidance to be possible.

Comment: You're describing an XY problem and concentrating on a proposed solution. The consequence 'Naturally' isn't in evidence. Ask a specific question. Without further qualification it isn't clear you're not describing random access memory (which wouldn't be 'too much').

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a serialization issue, instead of multiplexing, just latch, shift to the output, and latch there.

Otherwise if you want to keep with multiplexing, be aware how much delay your method is adding. all that signal switching costs time.